# compile gnu make with msys2/mingw on Windows

Tags: gnu-make, msys2

I need gnu make for Windows with case insensitive flag.
Tried the current version 4.3 with msys2/mingw, and it brings some errors on compiling.

All I need is
./configure --enable-case-insensitive-file-system

The first errors seem to be winsock related, therefore I added "ac_cv_header_winsock2_h=no".
But the next errors seem are in dirent.c, I don't know how to solve them...

It should obviously work somehow :) because it is already included with msys2, but with case sensitivity.
I searched a lot and did not find any hint... any help welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: I would start with [MSYS2 `make` build script](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/blob/master/make/PKGBUILD). It has a list of dependencies, and the ./configure flags. They're building it in the [`MSYS` environment](https://www.msys2.org/docs/environments/), so you should do the same.

Comment: This is what I had to do...
However, the build script only calls the build_w32.bat... the configure calls is also not working.